# Create an account through a REST api

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express

I'd like to create a **secure** API in `node.js` for my mobile app.
Basically I would like users to be able to create their account through the app (with email and password), so I'm wondering what would be the right way. I imagine something like this:

```
curl -d '{"email":"hello@world", "password":"1234"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://myapi/users
```

So server would reply with the new created user and oauth usual tokens in order to authenticate the next requests so:

```
{
   id: '1234455656',
   email: 'hello@world',
   auth_token: 'my_auth_token'
   refresh_token: 'my_refresh_token'
}
```

It just doesn't feel like the best secure way to do it as anyone could create a user even without the app, and I'm wondering if this is how apps usually deal with this? Maybe there's even something better than express to do this well

Comment: Consider using an [OAuth](https://oauth.net)-backed system and the standard tokens it can generate. You can do this easily in Express with [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org).

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want anyone to be able to create an account?

Here are a few ideas:

To prevent users from creating accounts without the app, require an api key with the signup request (in a header for example) that is bundled with the app build.

You should also require users to verify their email addresses, and you could clean out user accounts which have not verified their email address after a period of time.

Comment: I like the api key, i've just realized that through https it would be at least hidden when inspecting the http requests from the app.

Comment: Yes, however, the key cannot really be hidden from savvy users who might want to inspect the app more closely (or any client application).

Comment: yes, thats a minimal security, i actually found a complete workflow:
 https://itnext.io/an-oauth-2-0-introduction-for-beginners-6e386b19f7a9